# Is it possible to load a storyboard in an iOS Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Is it possible to load a storyboard in an iOS Playground? 
Follow the steps in this questions:

[How do you instantiate a Storyboard from a file within an iOS playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176123/how-do-you-instantiate-a-storyboard-from-a-file-within-an-ios-playground)

Compiled Main.storyboard using

```
ibtool --compile MainMenu.nib MainMenu.storyboard
```

Added it to the `Resources` folder of the playground. Then tried loading it:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

This resulting in an error:

```
Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

Is this supported in XCode 7.3.1 or even XCode 8?

Comment: Not the whole story board file but you can insert design you want. Because StoryBoard itself a file.

Comment: @JAck Didn't quite understand. Can you rephrase, please. Do you mean I can add a single xib ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your storyboard init code works for me if I set up the resource section of the playground with the same structure as an app.

Resources->Base.lproj->Main.storyboardc

Comment: Can you please share your project. I'm not able to reproduce. Did you also compile the .storyboard ?

Comment: I copied a Base.lproj folder out of a compiled sample app and added it to Resources so, yes, it is a compiled storyboard.

Comment: I thought "storyboardc" was just misspelled

Answer (score 3):

After many attempts, I finally got this working. A few caveats:

1.. Compile the storyboard using

```
ibtool --compile MainMenu.storyboardc MainMenu.storyboard
```

Not using

```
ibtool --compile MainMenu.nib MainMenu.storyboard
```

2.. Place the compiled storyboardc file in the Resources folder of the playground, not the Sources folder

3.. Specify module name using --module flag when compiling. Otherwise, your outlets may cause a runtime error. For the playground book, the module name is Book_Sources. For your own playground, the module name is [Playground name]_Sources. Note I didn't find any of this in Apple's documentation, so it is subject to change.
The final command looks like this:

```
ibtool --compile MainMenu.storyboardc MainMenu.storyboard --module Book_Sources
```

Comment: @HaoDong I added some information regarding modules that I just discovered. See if this time it works.