# Add Playground to a Storyboard project: Could not find a storyboard ... in bundle NSBundle

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a working iOS project with Storyboards. Then I added a playground file to it with following content:

The

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

var str = "Hello, playground" 
let gameViewController = GameViewController.loadFromStoryboard() // <<<<- Fails
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = gameViewController
```

I am getting following error at line, where I `loadFromStoryboard()`:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle
```

What should I fix? 
There are tonnes of questions on stackoverflow with the above title/contents however, each has a very specific scenario. I have gone through many of them over past few days and I think that my scenario is distinct due to use of Playground hence I am posting again.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in an existing project, you can instantiate the storyboard by using your full bundle identifier, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135286/1822214):

```
let myBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.asad.MyProgram")
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: myBundle)
```

Please note that this *does* require that the playground is in the same workspace as the project with that particular bundle identifier.